# MS Access 2016 no reference to 15 Library and App malfunction

Tags: ms-access, reference

I was doing an application to create tickets on my work, for this I was working on MS Access 2016, everything went well, until I went to a meeting to show the functionality of the application and everything started to crumble.

The app has a login screen, user creation, ticket creation, submit, etc. 
When I create the ticket, when compiling it says that the library doesnt exist.

As soon as it opens in a computer it was getting an error regarding the 32-bit OS, but on another computer with the correct version it exploded because the library wasn't the correct.

My problem is:

I may be the only one on the department to have MS Access 2016, which means everyone that'll use this App is going to use it on MS Access 2013, which will lead to all the current errors regarding libraries. I searched all over the internet trying to download the library, if I could downgrade the library version, etc. No luck.

Tried to save in a lower version of database and no luck as well.

Is there any other way I can make this work even though i'm working on MS Access 2016 ? How can I fix this without having to start a whole new project?

Thanks in advance,

Diogo Martins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access is forward compatible but not backward.

for example, if you develop an application in Access 2010 and then move the application to Access 2016, everything will work fine. But you do develop in 2016 and run the application in 2010, you will get broken "MISSING" references in your VBA references.

You could get around this by dimming everything as an object over dimming as the specific reference type

Below is dimming using the specific reference:

```
Public Sub TestReference()
Dim objXLApp as excel.application
Dim objXLBook as excel.workbook

Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objXLBook = objXLApp.workbooks.open("Workbook path and name")
End Sub
```

Below is dimming using objects:

```
Public Sub TestObject()
Dim oExcel as object
dim oBook as object

Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.open ("Workbook path and name")
End Sub
```

You are not required to use a reference is you dim as objects

Try this solution and let me know if it works. if not, I will do more digging and will require to see your code in order to find the root of the problem.

Comment: So instead of dim like this:    Dim outlk As New Outlook.Application
          Dim mii As Outlook.MailItem
          Set mii = outlk.CreateItem(olMailItem)     I should use As objects?    Sorry for the not so clear comment, i don't know why, i can't format that well. @Chris

Comment: Dim outlk as object
Dim mii as object

Set outlk = createobject("Outlook.Applciation")
set mii = createitem(olmailitem)

Comment: Worked like a charm, did this work for being a more generic coding? So Access doesn't detect this is the newest version since the code is "old" in some way, only using objects? Thank you so much for the help!